# Quarkus startup is complaining about deprecated properties

Tags: java, datasource, quarkus

I had a quarkus project up and running on Ubuntu and my dev env was working fine. I then upgraded to a Mac and cloned the project, ran `mvn quarkus:dev` expecting it all to work fine but sadly that's not the case :(

I get met with a nasty stacktrace telling me that `quarkus.datasource.url` and `quarkus.datasource.driver` is deprecated and removed from quarkus versions 1.3 and 1.9. Thing is I don't use either of those properties!!

Here is my **application.properties**

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db?sslmode=disable
quarkus.datasource.username=admin
quarkus.datasource.password=password
quarkus.liquibase.migrate-at-start=true
quarkus.liquibase.change-log=db/changelog/db.changelog-master.xml
```

And here is the **stacktrace**

```
Caused by: io.quarkus.runtime.configuration.ConfigurationException: quarkus.datasource.url and quarkus.datasource.driver have been deprecated in Quarkus 1.3 and removed in 1.9. Please use the new datasource configuration as explained in https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource.
    at io.quarkus.agroal.deployment.AgroalProcessor.build(AgroalProcessor.java:76)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at io.quarkus.deployment.ExtensionLoader$2.execute(ExtensionLoader.java:972)
    at io.quarkus.builder.BuildContext.run(BuildContext.java:277)
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:2046)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1578)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1452)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:479)
```

I am pretty confused as this was working on 1 machine and not the other! Any tips/ideas on how to get passed this?

Comment: "*Any tips/ideas on how to get passed this?*" - "*`quarkus.datasource.url and quarkus.datasource.driver have been deprecated in Quarkus 1.3 and removed in 1.9. Please use the new datasource configuration as explained in https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource.`*"

Comment: are you 100% sure there's no system property, env var, .env file, config/application.properties or custom defined location properties file picked up?

Comment: @Turing85 other than the obvious, assumed I didn't have to state that as I included my application.properties file and showed nothing in it!

Comment: @peterulb will have to verify that!

Comment: @Dan please remember that in the .env file it's named `QUARKUS_DATASOURCE_URL`. Might be helpful when Ctrl+F the project :)

Comment: @peterulb it was env variables set a long time ago!! Thanks for the direction on this

Answer (score 3):

As per Config Sources, quarkus takes multiple sources into account. Mainly

1. (400) System properties
2. (300) Environment variables
3. (295) .env file in the current working directory
4. (260) Quarkus Application configuration file in $PWD/config/application.properties
5. (250) Quarkus Application configuration file application.properties in classpath
6. (100) MicroProfile Config configuration file META-INF/microprofile-config.properties in classpath

Additionally properties found in locations defined by the `smallrye.config.locations` property or `SMALLRYE_CONFIG_LOCATIONS` environment variable.

This is also set when `quarkus.kubernetes.app-config-map=<name of the config map containing the configuration>` is used as a single step alternative to the following:

> Quarkus supports passing configuration from external locations (via Smallrye Config). This usually requires setting an additional environment variable or system propertiy. When you need to use a secret or a config map for the purpose of application configuration, you need to:
> define a volume
> mount the volume
> create an environment variable for SMALLRYE_CONFIG_LOCATIONS

So in any of these cases, one must be careful that a property source with a higher ordering ordinal doesn't override the default provided by the application.properties.

Answer (score 0):

```
Change application.properties and use application.yml with the following syntax:
 
quarkus:
  datasource:
    db-kind: postgresql
    jdbc:
      url: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db?sslmode=disable
      username: admin
      password: password
      driver: org.postgresql.Driver
  liquibase:
    migrate-at-start: true
    change-log: db/changelog/db/changelog-master/xml
```

Comment: How the yaml format of configuration will solve the issue?